# Does the android market use your merchant API callback URL during the Google checkout process for paid applications?

Tags: android, google-play

If I have a paid app on Android Market, will my merchant API callback URL get a hit when the customer goes to check out? I am wondering how merchants/vendors/developers secure their applications for android market.

I have used google checkout before to implement a custom integration, so I understand how that all works. What I do not see anywhere that I have looked is what, if any, integration does the merchant/developer have with the Android Market checkout process? I understand that the market uses google checkout, but in that case the market hosts the checkout process and not the merchant, so it's not clear whether they give your URL a call.

So where is the hook? Am I right in assuming it is the merchant API callback URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App on Android market - HTTP notifications don't come](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459858/app-on-android-market-http-notifications-dont-come)