# App on Android market - HTTP notifications don't come

Tags: android, google-play

PREAMBLE: the question is wildly obsolete. There's no more Google Checkout, no more Checkout API, and no more notification settings in Wallet Console.

---

I have a paid app on Android Market. I've set up an HTTPS notification URL in Google Checkout settings. Yet notifications don't come.

My Google Checkout settings under Integration go like this:

- My company will only post digitally signed carts - checked
- API callback URL - provided, it's HTTPS and it's valid
- Notification as XML - checked
- API version - 2.5
- Notification filtering - checked

Please, what am I doing wrong? Are realtime order notifications supported for Android Market at all? If so, is there a separate UI for setting those up?

EDIT: any data points would be welcome. If you sell stuff on the Market and do get those HTTP notifications, let's compare the setups.

EDIT2: seriously considering timed polling of my Google Checkout account. :(

EDIT3: contacted Google Checkout support. No substantial response for over a week. :(( On the brighter side, it is possible to retrieve the list of one's Google Checkout orders, with date and state filtering. On to retrieving order details...

Comment: Maby you also know the answer to this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793753/android-in-app-payments-merchants-api-how-to-write-and-read-custom-param-in-t

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The support rep told me it's by design, I should implement account polling with notification history API.

Specifically: https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API describes how to get the list of orders in given state

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_History_API lets you retrieve order details (getting just the "new order" notification is sufficient in my case).

EDIT: you cannot use some parts of the Google Checkout API with Android Market orders (like marking as archived).

This is not documented. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173461/api-level-difference-between-google-checkout-and-android-market-documented).

Comment: Both links are broken

Comment: The Checkout API I've referred to exists no longer anyway. The functionality itself is partially available elsewhere. But the premise of the question - that Checkout sends notifications about orders - is gone as well.