# API-level difference between Google Checkout and Android Market documented?

Tags: android, google-play, google-checkout, sales-analytics

### PREAMBLE: this question is wildly obsolete. There's no more Google Checkout and no more API.

Android Market uses Google Checkout for paid app sales. Google Checkout has a fairly extensive API. The behavior of Android Market accounts is markedly different from that documented for vanilla Google Checkout. Some examples:

- URL callbacks upon sales don't work
- Some XML API methods are not supported - e. g. `<archive-order>`
- In XML notifications, undocumented elements - e. g. `<agent-private-data>` under `<shopping-cart>`

Are those Android specifics documented anywhere?