# Google Merchant Key for Android developers outside US and UK

Tags: android, google-checkout

According to [How do we verify Android in-app billing receipt on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384246/how-do-we-verify-android-in-app-billing-receipt-on-the-server-side), Android developers can use Google Checkout API (https://developers.google.com/checkout/) in order to verify Android in-apps on the server side.
In order to take the most of all the functionality of this API (there is a good PHP library in http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/wiki/Documentation) we need the Merchant Key, but it looks like the Merchant Key is only pertinent to the Google Checkout API for web sites (not for Android), and people outside US or UK, cannot get this Merchant Key.

Is that true? Can't Android Developer get the Merchant Key (Google Play Developer Console says that License keys are now managed for each app individually, but I don't know how to get o set-up the Merchant Key)?
If not, how can we verify Android in-apps on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You verify by verifying the signature with the public key you get from the developer console. If you don't have access to a merchant key, you cannot use the Google checkout API and there is nothing you can do about it, besides incorporating a company in the US or UK, perhaps.