# query android market place

Tags: android, google-play

I am building an application that at some point involves In-App Billing.
To add a level of security, after an item is successfully purchased, a server will ask Android Market if the item was purchased by a specific user.

Is there any API (Java, C, any language) that would allow the server to query Android Market if a purchase was successful?

Regards

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459858/app-on-android-market-http-notifications-dont-come). There's an XML over HTTP API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that would be in In-App billing itself i.e "after the item is successfully purchased" means that the user has bought it, no further checks would be needed.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: I know that ... but the scenario I am involved in implies having a server that requests my application to buy something. The requirement I have is that the server must somehow query Android Market to perform the check if the purchase was successful. Please don't ask why (I have to live with this too), I am just asking if there is an API that would allow Android Market query.